# CSV Data import in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to add relationship between existing employee nodes in my sample database from csv file using the following commands:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///newmsg1.csv' AS line 
WITH line
MATCH (e:Employee {mail: line.fromemail}), (b:Employee {mail: line.toemail})
CREATE (e)-[m:Message]->(b);
```

The problem i am facing is that, while there are only **71253** entries in the csv file in which each entry has a "fromemail" and "toemail", 
I am getting "**Created 240643 relationships, completed after 506170 ms**."  as the output. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that :Employee(mail) is unique for all :Employee nodes? Try creating a unique constraint here, and if you get an error preventing you from doing so, then you have multiple :Employee nodes with the same mail property, and your matches and subsequent relationship creations will be creating more relationships than there are lines.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thank you for your reply now I see that there are only 240 unique emails for all employee nodes. Now how can solve the problem now..

Comment: @InverseFalcon As you mentioned, I will try to create unique constraint for the mail and see how it is going ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your create to [CREATE UNIQUE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///newmsg1.csv' AS line 
WITH line
MATCH (e:Employee {mail: line.fromemail}), (b:Employee {mail: line.toemail})
CREATE UNIQUE (e)-[m:Message]->(b);
```

From the [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/#query-create-unique):

> `CREATE UNIQUE` is in the middle of `MATCH` and `CREATE` — it will match
>   what it can, and create what is missing. `CREATE UNIQUE` will always
>   make the least change possible to the graph — if it can use parts of
>   the existing graph, it will.

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno Peres!

Comment: Hi Bruno I have doubt regarding the Match clause. I am having a list of employees in a csv file. I want to find out the number of messages sent by all these employees to employees which are not in the list. Is this the correct query to get what I want?   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///subgroup.csv' AS line 
WITH line
MATCH (b:Employee{pkey :line.subgroup})-[r:Message]->(c:Employee) WHERE c.pkey <> line.subgroup RETURN COUNT(r)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MERGE` to ensure uniqueness of relationships:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///newmsg1.csv' AS line 
WITH line
MATCH (e:Employee {mail: line.fromemail}), (b:Employee {mail: line.toemail})
MERGE (e)-[m:Message]->(b);
```